# Eager loading in EF1.0

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a many-to-many relationship:

Application ->
Applications_Servers ->
Server

This is set up in my Entity Data Model and all is well.  My problem is that I'd like to eager-load the whole graph of Applications so that I have an `IEnumerable<Applications>`, each Application member populated with the `Servers` collection associated by the many-to-many relationship.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but according to my research there *must* be a navigation property between Application and Server.  This is not the case for me because my `Applications_Servers` join table has more in it than just the two keys.  Therefore, there is no navigation property directly between Application and Server, and this doesn't work:

```
    var apps = (from a in context.Application.Include("Server")
               select a).ToList();
```

I get an error saying there is no navigation property on Application called "Server", and that's correct, there is none.

How do I write the query to eager-load my Applications **with** their Servers in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the existing navigation properties.

```
context
   .Application
   .Include("Applications_Servers")
   .Include("Applications_Servers.Server")
```

This should eager load all associated `Applications_Servers` and `Server` entities.